# getting Clustering/Bucketing columns programmatically

Tags: sql, hive, sqlalchemy, presto, amazon-athena

For reference, I am connecting to `amazon-athena` via `sqlalchemy` using essentially:

```py
create_engine(
            f'awsathena+rest://:@athena.{myRegion}.amazonaws.com:443/{athena_schema}?s3_staging_dir={myS3_staging_path}',
            echo=True)
```

In most relational databases that adhere to the ANSI-`SQL` standard, I can programmatically get the **partition** columns of a table by running something like the following:

```sql
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name='myTable' and table_schema='mySchema'
    and extra_info = 'partition key'
```

However the **bucketing** or **clustering** columns seem to not be similarly flagged.  I know I can access this information via:

```sql
show create table mySchema.myTable
```

but I am interested in clean programmatical solution, if one exists.  I am trying to not reinvent the wheel.  Please show me how to do this or point me to the relevant documentation.

Thank you in advance.

PS: It would also be great if other **information** about the table, like location of files and **storage format** were also accessible programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena uses Glue Data Catalog to store metadata about databases and tables. I don't know how much of this is exposed in `information_schema`, and there is very little documentation about it.

However, you can get everything Athena knows by querying the Glue Data Catalog directly. In this case if you call [`GetTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_GetTable.html) (e.g. `aws glue get-table …`) you will find the bucketing information in `Table.StorageDescriptor.BucketColumns`.

The `GetTable` call will also give you the storage format and the location of the files (but for a partitioned table you need to make additional calls with [`GetPartitions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_GetPartitions.html) to retrieve the location of each partition's data).

Comment: I am going to try this.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Again, thank you @theo.  This is exactly what I was looking for.